# How to make a .find() using a record id on one to one relationship

Tags: node.js, sails.js, sails-mongo

In sails-mongo(0.10.0-rc3/beta) it looks like the foreign id is converted to `ObjectID` so if I have a two models with one to one relationship how do I query using an id?

Example:

```
ModelA
attributes: {
 user: { model: 'User' }
}

User.js
attributes: {
  ...
}
```

Now I want to query do like `ModelA.find(user: req.session.user).exec(console.log)` and the log returns `null []` instead of the all the items in ModelA that belongs to the current user.

Edit:
I tried converting `req.session.user` again to ObjectID using the mongodb module `new ObjectID(req.session.user)` and everything works. I'm not sure why it didn't work the last time.

Thanks

Comment: Have you verified that `req.session.user` contains a valid user ID?

Comment: Yes, I printed out req.session.user and it returned the correct user id, when I do `typeof req.session.id` I get sting so I'm wondering maybe I should convert it to ObjectID but still no result is being returned.

Answer (score 0):

In `sails-redis@0.10.0-rc3` querying associated models seems to behave as expected.

First, I created a basic `User` model:

```
module.exports = {
    attributes: {
        name: 'string'
    }
};
```

Second the `ModelA` model with the associated `User`:

```
module.exports = {
    attributes: {
        user: { model: 'User' }
    }
};
```

Then I created a small `mocha` test for checking the association query and reducing any errors introduced somewhere else (e.g. in your session handling):

```
var expect = require('chai').expect,
    sails = require('sails'),
    async = require('async');

describe('sails-mongo associations', function() {

    before(function (done) {
        sails.lift(function (err, sails) {
            done(err);
        });
    });

    after(function (done) {
        sails.lower(function (err) {
            done(err);
        });
    });

    beforeEach(function(done) {
        async.auto({
            deleteUsers: function(done) {
                User.destroy(done);
            },
            deleteModelA: function(done) {
                ModelA.destroy(done);
            }
        }, function(err) {
            done(err);
        });
    });

    describe("#find", function() {
        it("should allow to find a record using an associated model", function(done) {
            User.create({ name: 'Test User' }).exec(function(err, user) {
                expect(err).to.be.null;
                expect(user).to.contain.key('id');

                ModelA.create({ user: user.id }).exec(function(err, model) {
                    expect(err).to.be.null;
                    expect(model).to.contain.keys('id', 'user');

                    ModelA.find({ user: user }).populate('user').exec(function(err, model) {
                        expect(err).to.be.null;
                        expect(model).not.to.be.null.and.contain.key('user', user);
                        done();
                    });
                }); 
            });
        });

    });
});
```

The mocha test completes successfully without any error. Which probably means (as Scott Gress already assumed) your `req.session.user` variable does not contain the value you expect. Internal conversion to mongos `ObjectID` is working.

Cheers,
David

Comment: I've tried this and I get and empty array `[]` and the model.user is `undefined`. I've printed the user and it's returning the correct user data. I also tried `ModelA.find({user: user.id})` instead of `{user: user}`but still no result returning.

Comment: Does your ModelA document contain any data at all? To be sure that your database is in the correct state, you could try fetching the whole document and look for the data manually.

Comment: Yes I checked both the user and modela table and there are contents. and all contents are connected to a user and same with the user.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem myself. It seems `sails-mongo` wouldn't convert your string id's to `ObjectId()`-syntax unless it was a primary key (`_id`).

[Luckily, this is fixed in a recent commit](https://github.com/balderdashy/sails-mongo/commit/2200f6d3a396582fdc97e76cc59e78736bdb0933)

Update your `package.json` to use the master-branch, or wait for an rc4-release.

Comment: Thanks, yes that's what I observe also and I'm glad this issue has been fixed.